# How to bind DataGrid's ItemsSource to one ViewModel and DataGrid's SelectedItem to another?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, data-binding

C#

```
DataContext="{Binding ProveedoresViewModel, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource LocatorViewModel}}"
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid Margin="10" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ListaProveedores, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          GridLinesVisibility="All"
          SelectedItem="{Binding ProveedorSeleccionado, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          BorderThickness="1" 
          BorderBrush="Black">
```

`ListaProveedores` Is ViewModel1, `ProveedorSeleccionado` is ViewModel2.
I need to specify the datacontext for `ProveedorSeleccionado`

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the LocatorViewModel resource expose both view models (ProveedoresViewModel and "ViewModel2" or whatever the other one is called) through public properties, you could just bind the SelectedItem property of the DataGrid to a sub-property of "ViewModel2":

```
<DataGrid Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaProveedores, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" GridLinesVisibility="All"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel2.ProveedorSeleccionado, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
```

You could also explicitly set the Source of the binding to another resource, e.g.:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding ProveedorSeleccionado, Source={StaticResource ViewModel2}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```